# shiro intercept all js,picture ,css and can't access to the method

Tags: spring-mvc, shiro

Shiro intercept all js,picture ,css and can't access to the method

This is the web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>


<!-- 前端控制器的配置 -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

    <!--指定spring配置文件的位置 -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- 所有以.html和.json的请求都由dispatcherServlet来处理的配置 -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<!--?Shiro?filter 需放在所有filter之前 -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>targetFilterLifecycle</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>utf-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>ftlFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.cms.filter.FtlFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ftlFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.ftl</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>manage</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.cms.filter.ManageFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>manage</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/manage/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>




<!-- 让web应用程序启动那个时自动添加属性文件 -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- 以Listener方式启动LOG4j -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- 以Listener方式启动spring -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.IntrospectorCleanupListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.WebAppRootListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>20</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404.htm</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/500.htm</location>
</error-page>
```

this is the applicationContext.xml

```
<!-- 自动扫描的包名 -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.cms"></context:component-scan>

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<cache:annotation-driven key-generator="keyGeneratorService"/>

<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/WEB-INF/static/"
    cache-period="31556926" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/upload/**" location="/upload/"
    cache-period="31556926" />


<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
        <bean class="com.cms.filter.GlobalInterceptor"></bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>

<!-- spring自己的换管理器，这里定义了两个缓存位置名称 ，既注解中的value -->
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager">
    <property name="caches">
        <set>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean"
                p:name="default" />
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean"
                p:name="config" />
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean"
                p:name="folder" />
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean"
                p:name="article" />
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean"
                p:name="media" />
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- 在XML配置文件中加入外部属性文件，当然也可以指定外部文件的编码 -->
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="com.cms.util.PropertyUtils">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:shishuocms.properties</value> <!-- 指定外部文件的编码 -->
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>


<!-- FreeMarker的配置 -->
<bean id="freeMarkerConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
    <property name="templateLoaderPaths" value="/WEB-INF/static/" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="freemarkerSettings">
        <props>
            <prop key="template_update_delay">10</prop>
            <prop key="defaultEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="url_escaping_charset">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="locale">zh_CN</prop>
            <prop key="boolean_format">true,false</prop>
            <prop key="time_format">HH:mm:ss</prop>
            <prop key="datetime_format">yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss</prop>
            <prop key="date_format">yyyy-MM-dd</prop>
            <prop key="number_format">#.##</prop>
            <prop key="whitespace_stripping">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- 配置 FreeMarker视图解析器 -->
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView"></property>
    <property name="cache" value="false" />
    <!-- <property name="prefix" value="" /> -->
    <property name="suffix" value=".ftl" /><!--可为空,方便实现自已的依据扩展名来选择视图解释类的逻辑 -->
    <property name="contentType" value="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <property name="exposeRequestAttributes" value="true" />
    <property name="exposeSessionAttributes" value="true" />
    <property name="exposeSpringMacroHelpers" value="true" />
</bean>


<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClass}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

<!-- 创建SqlSessionFactory，同时指定数据源 -->
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<!-- 配置事务管理器 -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<!--创建数据映射器，数据映射器必须为接口 -->
<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <property name="annotationClass" value="org.springframework.stereotype.Repository" />
    <property name="basePackage" value="com.cms.dao" />
</bean>

<!-- shiro -->
<bean id="securityManager"
    class="org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager">
    <property name="realm" ref="shiroDbRealm" />
</bean>

<!-- 項目自定义的Realm -->
<bean id="shiroDbRealm" class="com.cms.realm.ShiroDbRealm" ></bean>

<!-- Shiro Filter -->
<bean id="shiroFilter"
    class="org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean">
    <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager" />
    <property name="loginUrl" value="/" />
    <property name="successUrl" value="index.htm" />
    <property name="unauthorizedUrl" value="/static/manage/500" />
    <property name="filterChainDefinitions">
        <value>
        /login = anon
        /validateCode = anon
        /** = authc
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

    <!-- 开启Shiro注解的Spring配置方式的beans。在lifecycleBeanPostProcessor之后运行 -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator"
    depends-on="lifecycleBeanPostProcessor" />
<bean
    class="org.apache.shiro.spring.security.interceptor.AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor">
    <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager" />
</bean>

    <!-- Shiro生命周期处理器-->  
<bean id="lifecycleBeanPostProcessor"   
class="org.apache.shiro.spring.LifecycleBeanPostProcessor"/>  




<!-- shiro为集成spring -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="org.apache.shiro.authz.UnauthorizedException">/static/manage/500</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

My login.ftl submit url is

```
action="${BASE_PATH}/admin/login.json"
```

The java is

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/login.json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public JsonVo<String> adminLogin{}
```

Comment: i submit ,but it is only refresh the page,and  there is no error in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i modify the applicationContext.xml with

```
<property name="filterChainDefinitions">
        <value>
        /** = anon 
        </value>
    </property>
```

and is ok